# How to achieve interactive shell attack?

Tags: exploit, shellcode, user-interface

Usually when a person gets a shell by attacking some vulnerabilities, what a person gets is non-interactive shell.

So when I call FTP interactive client, shell fails.

Is there any way I can do interactive stuffs without uploading some graphical remote programs - such as VNC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphical shells are heavy on the bandwidth, unreasonably complex, and usually unnecessary anyway. "Shell" in an exploitation context usually refers to a text-only shell; `bash` or `sh` or `zsh` for example. Or `cmd.exe` on windows. The idea is that if you can only run *one* command, then the one to run is a shell, bind STDIN/STDOUT to a network interface, and then connect to it with something like telnet. Then you can type whatever commands you want.

Comment: oh.. so telnet can do interactive stuffs?

Comment: @Dotzio um, yeah. Or `nc` or any other raw network tool. This is the sort of thing that should be obvious if you know what you're doing, so perhaps going over some basics on how network programming works would be helpful?

Comment: nc seemed to be non-interactive according to my experience... for example, when I entered nc command itself, it should bring "cmd line: " that allows me to type some stuffs and execute. (of course, nc and using parameters would be ok, and I know this.)

Comment: I just found some resource saying that netcat is non-interactive while telnet is interactive. I may try telnet. Thanks.

Comment: both are roughly identical, though netcat does more interesting unusual stuff telnet handles all the subtle absurdities of a genuine telnet session (which no one uses anymore). check the man pages for how to use them.

Comment: @Polynomial shellcode is code to bring up a shell -- that's not always what it does, but that's what the name means

Comment: @tylerl That's the source of the term, yes. Doesn't mean it still means that, though :)

Comment: @Polynomial yes, but in this context, I was referring to the *use* of shellcode, not its definition.